Struggling to send a PNG file to AWS Bedrock Agent
I have set up an AWS bedrock agent and am successfully sending text requests and receiving responses.
I need to send across a PNG file for the Agent to view and return the contents as JSON.
This is my current code:
import {
    BedrockAgentRuntimeClient,
    InvokeAgentCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent-runtime";

import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import https from 'https';

async function getImageData(imageUrl) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(imageUrl, (res) => {
            const chunks = [];

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                const imageData = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                resolve(imageData);
            });

            res.on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    });
}`

`async function invokeBedrockAgent(prompt, sessionId, imageUrl) {
    const client = new BedrockAgentRuntimeClient({
        region: "eu-west-2",
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        },
    });

    const agentId = process.env.AGENTID;
    const agentAliasId = process.env.AGENTALIASID;

    const imageData = await getImageData(imageUrl);
    const imageUint8Array = new Uint8Array(imageData);

    const input = {
        agentId,
        agentAliasId,
        sessionId,
        sessionState: {
            files: [
                {
                    name: "image-file",
                    source: {
                        sourceType: "BYTE_CONTENT",
                        byteContent: {
                            mediaType: "image/png",
                            //data: imageUint8Array,
                            data: new TextEncoder().encode(imageData.toString('base64')),
                        },
                    },
                    useCase: "CHAT",
                },
            ],
        },
        inputText: prompt,
    };

    const command = new InvokeAgentCommand(input);

    try {
        let completion = "";
        const response = await client.send(command);

        if (!response.completion) {
            throw new Error("Completion is undefined");
        }

        for await (let chunkEvent of response.completion) {
            if (chunkEvent.chunk) {
                const chunk = chunkEvent.chunk;
                const decodedResponse = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(chunk.bytes);
                completion += decodedResponse;
            }
        }

        console.log("Final completion response:", completion);
        return { sessionId: sessionId, completion };
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", err);
        throw err;
    }
}

I am getting this response:
Error occurred: ValidationException: The overridden prompt that you provided is incorrectly formatted. Check the format for errors, such as invalid JSON, and retry your request.
    at de_ValidationExceptionRes (/Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent-runtime/dist-cjs/index.js:1683:21)
    at de_ValidationException_event (/Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent-runtime/dist-cjs/index.js:1934:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent-runtime/dist-cjs/index.js:1782:30
    at async Object.deserializer (/Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@smithy/eventstream-serde-universal/dist-cjs/index.js:127:37)
    at async _SmithyMessageDecoderStream.asyncIterator (/Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@smithy/eventstream-codec/dist-cjs/index.js:430:28)
    at async invokeBedrockAgent (file:///Users/JG/Desktop/storm%20ai/functions/bedrockTesting.js:81:24) {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: undefined,
    requestId: undefined,
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined
  }
}
node:internal/process/promises:391
    triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
    ^

ValidationException: The overridden prompt that you provided is incorrectly formatted. Check the format for errors, such as invalid JSON, and retry your request.
    at de_ValidationExceptionRes (/Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent-runtime/dist-cjs/index.js:1683:21)
    at de_ValidationException_event (/Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent-runtime/dist-cjs/index.js:1934:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-agent-runtime/dist-cjs/index.js:1782:30
    at async Object.deserializer (/Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@smithy/eventstream-serde-universal/dist-cjs/index.js:127:37)
    at async _SmithyMessageDecoderStream.asyncIterator (/Users/JG/Desktop/storm ai/node_modules/@smithy/eventstream-codec/dist-cjs/index.js:430:28)
    at async invokeBedrockAgent (file:///Users/JG/Desktop/storm%20ai/functions/bedrockTesting.js:81:24) {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: undefined,
    requestId: undefined,
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined
  }
}


This function works well if i exclude the file transfer.
The file is coming from cloudconvert storage (converted from a PDF)

did you figure this out yet?  I am likely to have the same issue, but with sending a PDF...The docs imply that the files param of sessionState are only for code interpretation, so perhaps that an issue?

Currently the Bedrock Agent Runtime only supports pdf, txt, doc, csv, xls and xlsx.
You need to use Bedrock Runtime if you need to send an image.
